# Update npm form 1.4.28 to 2.1.0

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I update version of npm from 1.4.8 to 2.1.0.
I tried the following. It did not help!

```css
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g npm@2.1.0
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@2.1.0 C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm -v
1.4.28

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

I have set the environment variable Path as below:

```css
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm;C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link that tells you methods for updating npm on Windows. I personally use the tool written by Microsoft https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Tried all of them. Did not help!

Comment: Did you try this package https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade?  This works for me, alternitvely you can update node to latest version?  It currently ships with version 2.7.3 of npm